# Is there a compact way to use a NOT IN (1,2,3) syntax when setting a variable?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Expressions like NOT IN (1,2,3) are valid in a where clause:

```
SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE 
  ((record_type NOT IN (2, 3, 7, 18, 19, 20, 21,12,13,22))
```

However if I want to move an elaborate expression composed of checks like the above from the WHERE clause to a SET @Var= statement, is there a way to do that without rewriting it like this:

```
declare @record_type int
set  @record_type  = 1

declare @ignoretype bit
IF    (@record_type <> 2)and(@record_type <> 3)and(@record_type <> 7)and
      (@record_type <> 12)and(@record_type <> 13)and
      ( (@record_type < 18) or (@record_type > 22))
     set @ignoretype=1
else
     set @ignoretype=0
```

I feel like it's really gross that what used to fit in one readable line is now a
gigantic gross mess.  Am I missing some syntax in SQL that is "NOT IN (1,2,3)" equivalent that works in `set @var =` or `IF` expressions? I would have written the above as:

```
select @ignoretype = (@record_type <> 2) ....
```

But you can't even use "<>" inequalities in a select statement in Microsoft SQL Server, which might be normal situation for DBAs and SQL experts, but as a relatively new SQL Server guy, I'm still finding the various syntax limits in various contexts confusing.

Answer (score 7):

There is no boolean datatype in SQL Server which is why `select @ignoretype = (@record_type <> 2)` doesn't work.

```
IF @record_type NOT IN ( 2, 3, 7, 18, 19, 20, 21, 12, 13, 22 )
  SET @ignoretype=1
ELSE
  SET @ignoretype=0
```

works fine. Or you could also do

```
SET @ignoretype = CASE
                    WHEN @record_type NOT IN ( 2, 3, 7, 18, 19, 20, 21, 12, 13, 22 ) 
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                  END
```

Or (if you are on 2012+)

```
SET @ignoretype = IIF(@record_type NOT IN ( 2, 3, 7, 18, 19, 20, 21, 12, 13, 22 ) ,1,0)
```

Comment: Wow. thanks for the IIF (2012+) idea.  When we move to SQL 2012 that would be great. Otherwise CASE is at least more readable than my `if (a<>1)and(a<>2)...`.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx